# model.fit validation_set ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

Looks like the train.df is expecting a different type of data or structure for the validation dataset but I am not sure of how to do because this is my first time working with a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/hgunraj/covidxct?select=test_COVIDx_CT-2A.txt) that has all images in a folder, then a metadata.csv and train,test, and validation .txts. The format of the txt columns is:

```
photo.png_string, diagnostic_number, xmin_number, xmax_number, ymin_number, ymax_number
```

The dataframes are shown as dtype:int64

I am loading the train,test, and validation from each .txt using:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('/location/.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
```

Also, the bounding boxes are not useful to me because I want to do a classification task without segmentation, so I am dropping xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax from each .txt

I am trying to use this simple model as a base to start:

```
num_classes = 3

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='gelu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='gelu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='gelu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='gelu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
  train_df,
  validation_data=val_df,
  epochs=25
)
```

When I try to execute this cell it returns:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9779/2327921962.py in <module>
     19   metrics=['accuracy'])
     20 
---> 21 model.fit(
     22   train_df,
     23   validation_data=val_df,

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1121               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1122 
-> 1123     if validation_data:
   1124       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
   1125           data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What would be the proper way to understand what type,tensor, or array should I convert the data to be accepted as input?

Thank you!

Comment: Your model's `fit` function isn't expecting a Pandas dataframe for the `validation_data` argument. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
model.fit(train_df.values,
          validation_data=val_df.values,
          epochs=25)
```